# How to load data from ajax on button press?

Tags: datatables

I'm trying to load search results into DataTables control. So after the user inputs some parameter and pressing the 'Search' button, then I would like to see the data loaded in the DataTables control. How do I initiate DataTables to load data through ajax only upon a user triggered event? All the examples I have seen all load data immediately. Thanks.

Comment: save the data into a var and then load the var on button press, just a thought.

Comment: @Andriy the data depends on what the user wants to search for. I cannot save the data in advance without knowing what the user wants to search for.

Comment: ok then attach a .click() to your button that would then run a function with the DT population. the function should also grab the user input from the text field and use it in the ajax call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [iDeferLoading](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options#iDeferLoading) in the initialisation code to prevent the datatable making a request on the initial page render.

```
'iDeferLoading': 1
```

Use [fnDraw](http://datatables.net/api#fnDraw) in your button click event to make the request with the user input as a parameter (see [fnServerParams](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnServerParams) for this)

```
oTable.fnDraw();
```